# Android Runnable runs faster after Resume

Tags: android, runnable

## Scenario

I have a runnable that outputs a the value of a variable every 1 second. The runnable starts when I start the mainActivity and runs throughout the app in the background.

## Problem

When I close the app (hidden state) and start the app again, the logcat starts outputting faster. It goes faster everytime I do this. Why ?

```
@Override
public void onStart()
{
    mHandler.postDelayed(myRunnable, 1000);
    super.onStart();
}

 public Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable()
 {
    @Override
    public void run()
    { 
       count ++;
       android.util.Log.w("     SYNC     ", "COUNT:"+count);
       mHandler.postDelayed(myRunnable, 1000);
    }
};
```

## SOLUTION / EDIT

Thank you all for answering ! I will give credit. However, it was @pskink who posted this [Android Runnable runs faster after Resume](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21131878/android-runnable-runs-faster-after-resume#comment31800567_21131878) , that solved it for me.

Comment: What does your onResume do?

Comment: Nothing at the moment. I had the code of the onStart in the onResume at first and swapped it to see if there is a difference.

Comment: because you start it again and again

Comment: @pskink Even if I put this code mHandler.postDelayed(myRunnable, 1000); in the onCreate method, it does the same thing.

Comment: @BrianRoach , I did try that too, removing it from the onStart and it does the same.

Comment: @Janpan so call removeCallbacksAndMessages(null) in onCreate

Comment: @pskink This works pretty good. Thanks ! Make an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

call
removeCallbacksAndMessages(null) before calling postDelayed

Comment: Thank you, this works great. I added removeCallbacksAndMessages(null) on the onCreate and then added this to the onResume , mHandler.removeCallbacks(myRunnable);
        mHandler.postDelayed(myRunnable, 1000); , and it works like it should.

Answer (score 2):

Because everytime you show app after hiding, onStart method is called, causing new instance of runnable to be created doing the same job.

So to solve this, you need to stop  your Runnable in onStop method.

As a general rule of thumb, when overriding [lifecycly methods](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html) like `onCreate`, `onStart`, `onResume` to trigger some continuous behaviour, you need to disable this behaviour in their respective counterparts (`onDestroy`, `onStop`, `onPause`).

So in your case, one way to disable behaviour triggered in onStart (starting new thread), is to stop this thread in onStop. For example:

```
public Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable()
 {
    private boolean stopped = false;
    public synchronized void stop() {
       stopped = true;             
    }
    public synchronized void reset() {
       stopped = false;             
    }
    @Override
    public void run()
    { 
       if(stopped) return;
       count ++;
       android.util.Log.w("     SYNC     ", "COUNT:"+count);
       mHandler.postDelayed(myRunnable, 1000);
    }
};
```

Now just call `myRunnable.stop()` in `onStop()` method. If you are reusing myRunnable instance, then call `myRunnable.reset()` in `onStart()` to enable it again.

Comment: Even if I put this code mHandler.postDelayed(myRunnable, 1000); in the onCreate method, it does the same thing.

Comment: if you use onCreate to trigger behaviour, disable that behaviour in onDestroy, if you use onStart, then you should use onStop to disable behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this image will help.  If you move your code to onCreate it should be OK.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

try

```
removeCallbacks(myRunnable)
```

in onPause()
and post the callbacks in onResume()

EDIT (including my comments into the answer):

When you return to the Activity, the Activity is in fact re-created, so you have two Activities: one shown and one invisible. And the runnables still repost themselves, each one having an implicit pointer to the Activity that created it... This is usually called a leak, or an *activity leak*.

Also please note that code that runs without user interaction should not be placed into an Activity, it should be a Service.

In addition, if counter is not static, you cannot access it after your activity leaves the screen.

From the MVC (*Model--View--Controller*) viewpoint, Activity=*Controller*. The *View* is the view hierarchy specified in the layout XML, we can create our own custom view classes, but usually we reuse the existing ones. And the *Model* is what must survive after the screen turns by 90 degrees (the Activity and the view hierarchy get re-created when orientation changes).
The runnable re-post logic should likely belong to the *Model*.

Comment: This causes the runnable to stop when I leave the activity. This however is not what I want.

Comment: When you return to the Activity, the Activity is in fact re-created, so you have two Activities: one shown and one invisible. And the runnables still repost themselves, each one having an implicit pointer to the Activity that created it... This is usually called a leak, or an _activity leak_.

Comment: Also please note that code that runs without user interaction should not be placed into an Activity, it should be a Service.

Comment: In addition, if `counter` is not static, you cannot access it after your activity leaves the screen.

Comment: Thanks for all the input. I have learned quite a bit now, even though I have been developing for android for a few years now. This has improved my insight into the activity lifecycle.

Answer (score 1):

You can ask if you already have one runnable at onStart(). I if it is null, you create the new runnable And if it is not null you do nothing

Comment: But in this case the pointer to the runnable, as well as the counter, should be static.