# Runnable in Fragment runs faster after Resume

Tags: android, android-fragments, runnable, timertask

I have already had a look at the question here: [Android Runnable runs faster after Resume](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21131878/android-runnable-runs-faster-after-resume)
but it does not solve my problem.
I have a runnable in a fragment, that changes the image every 5 seconds. When I first move to the fragment, it is the first fragment in the activity, it is fine: the images change every 5 seconds.
However, if I move to another fragment and come back, the runnable runs faster, so some images are changed every 2 seconds.
I have tried all the questions I could find on the topic, and still I am not able to do this right, so help will be very much appreciated.
Here is my code:

```
public class Home_Fragment extends Fragment implements RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener {

  Runnable wowUpdateResults;
  Handler wowHandler = new Handler();
  int wowdelay =0 ;
  int wowperiod = 5000;
  Timer wowtimer = new Timer();

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.wow_layout, container, false);
    ....
    wowUpdateResults = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            WowAnimateandSlideShow();
        }
    };

    wowtimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
             public void run() {
                 System.out.println("I am on scheduled at fixed rate");
                 wowHandler.post(wowUpdateResults);
             }
         }, wowdelay, wowperiod);
    return view;
}// end of onCreateView

private void WowAnimateandSlideShow() {

  ... //code to get the right image to be shown
  Animation rotateimage2 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity().getBaseContext(), R.anim.fade_in);
  wowprayer.startAnimation(rotateimage2);
}

public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();

  if (wowHandler != null){
        System.out.println("I am on the onPause, removing calls "+wowHandler);
        wowHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(wowUpdateResults);
    }
}

 public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    wowHandler.postDelayed(wowUpdateResults, 5000); // from the above mentioned question
 }
```

Also, the removeCallbacksAndMessages does not seem to be working, when the user moves away from this fragment there are still calls to the runnable.
Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be cause `Timer` is not stopped. Cancel the`Timer` in your `onPost` method:

```
public void onPause(){ 
    super.onPause(); 

  if (wowHandler != null){ 
        System.out.println("I am on the onPause, removing calls "+wowHandler);
        wowHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(wowUpdateResults);
    } 

  if(wowTimer != null){
     wowTimer.cancel();
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you. If I do that, which I have tried, then it crashes when it comes back as the timer has been cancelled and it cannot be started.

Comment: the error I get when I cancel the timer is 'java.lang.IllegalStateException: Timer was canceled'

Comment: I got it to work with your suggestion and then resetting the timer in the OnResume. Thanks a lot!